# How to install latest uWSGI/stable on Ubuntu with apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, uwsgi, apt-get, apt

I've done the below on a fresh ubuntu/trusty install:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install uwsgi
```

Which ends up installing 1.9.17.1-debian. According to the uWSGI website, 2.0.10 is the latest stable version.

How would I go about updating my repositories to reflect this? I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux and don't understand why apt-get update isn't working as I understand it should be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-get` installs from Ubuntu repo which is behind any specific app repo. With Python, you usually install packages from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) (which is normally up-to-date) with `pip` and into a `virtualenv`.

Comment: Correct, but I personally do not install uwsgi in a venv. I install it system-level because the nginx I'm running it behind is also installed system-level. Just my 0.02. So specifically, I run $ pip install uwsgi

Comment: @ShaneH but the ubuntu repo contains an  init.d script, if i install it using pip, we have to write upstart script by ourself. seems hard for beginners.